# perforce workspace root is showing only hard drives

Tags: java, perforce

So this is odd for me and occurring multiple times now. I set up an perforce workspace copied from the MASTER and then it works for a few days then one day it just shows the hard drives where it should show the WorkSpace root folder.

All the update workspace and submit options are not allowed and then i have to currently REDO my workspace to get access again.

The settings haven't changed and IDK what could be causing this and how to fix it without a REDO of the workspace.

Is this a problem others have faced ? or just a bug in the software ?

How it does look:

[image: How it does look :(]

And because I assume this is the first question . I have tried the settings they are still currently setup correctly.

[image]

Comment: which software or IDE this screenshots come from?

Comment: what if you press an arrow near the hard drive?

Comment: @muescha, looks like it is P4

Comment: What does it mean to "REDO" a workspace?  (There is no "REDO" command in Perforce...)

Comment: Need more clarifications in this question. Not clear

Comment: yes correct it is perforce ( sorry that was just the tag and not in the question ) good old p4v.

Comment: please update your question with the details from comments and more

Comment: Okay, so the new screenshot shows the Root isn't "null" -- does the local root folder still exist?  P4V might default to just showing you the entire hard drive in the Workspace tab if your workspace root is gone.  What happens if you switch to the Depot tab?  What happens if you try to navigate to the workspace root from the Workspace tab?  And what does "REDO" mean?

Answer (score 5):

Funny enough, I ran into this issue today.
If someone has this issue make sure that in the top right of the Workspace area, the filter is set to "Workspace Root" and not "Entire Computer". The filter looks like a little funnel for those who don't know.

[Picture of Workspace filter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK3TB.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your workspace Root has been set to "null" to allow it to map multiple drives.  This is not in itself particularly problematic, but it's not something that should happen spontaneously.

The fact that you don't have permission to modify it AND it's changing out from underneath you makes me wonder if you might be using someone else's workspace.  Is your username in the "Owner" field?  Generally each user should have their own workspace(s).

Assuming that's the problem, the solution is to make your own workspace, and set it to "locked" to prevent anyone else from changing it.

Comment: well that is a option, I'll try this out and update this answer in a few days